# How to calculate total directions in multiple markers eclipse

Tags: java, android, distance

I need to get total distance in multiple directions, but when i run it just show current distance. As shown in image, when I click third marker it just calculate second direction (it should be first and second). Thank you very much :)

[image]

[image]

```
            // Fetching i-th route
            List<HashMap<String, String>> path = result.get(i);

            // Fetching all the points in i-th route
            for(int j=0;j<path.size();j++){
                HashMap<String,String> point = path.get(j);

                if(j==0){    // Get distance from the list
                    distance = (String)point.get("distance");
                    continue;
                }else if(j==1){ // Get duration from the list
                    duration = (String)point.get("duration");
                    continue;
                }

                double lat = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lat"));
                double lng = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lng"));
                LatLng position = new LatLng(lat, lng);

                points.add(position);
            }

            // Adding all the points in the route to LineOptions
            lineOptions.addAll(points);
            lineOptions.width(3);
        }
    tvDistanceDuration.setText(" Distance :"+distance + ", Duration:"+duration);
```

Comment: Please edit your question with relevant tag. Especially which language you are using.

Comment: okay .. i've do this

Comment: Hi. You seem to have a lot of code here. Is there a way you could post a [mcve] or highlight exactly where you think the issue is in the code?

Comment: okay .. i've summarize my code